# Как формировать JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть массив строк **произвольной** длины, например `["12", "31", "3", "12"]`, назовём его temp.
Как можно его превратить в подобное представление:

```
"users": [
  {
    "id": temp[0]
  },
  {
    "id": temp[1]
  },
  {
    "id": temp[2]
  },
  {
    "id": temp[3]
  }
]
```

Кто знаком с такой задачей, помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var temp = ["12", "31", "3", "12"];

function convertToObjects(strings) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
    result.push({ id: strings[i] });
  return result;
}

var users = convertToObjects(temp);
console.log(users);
```

Comment: Способ выше формировал строку, и в результате парсинга в JSON кидал ошибку. Этот способ хоть и длиннее, но зато формирует то, что сервер воспринимает, как JSON в результате

Comment: @ВладиславБублик, Вы шутите? `JSON.stringify` был только для компактности вывода в консоль. Просто уберите его.

Comment: @vp_arth я, честно говоря, считал, что у меня как раз и не хватает `stringify`, чтобы точно ответить на вопрос автора

Answer (score 6):

Можно воспользоваться методом [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
[Json.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) кодирует JS массив/объект в JSON-строку.

```js
let list = ["12", "31", "3", "12"].map(id => ({id}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
console.log(list);
```

---

#### Транскрипция:

- `let` - [объявление](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) переменной c блочной областью видимости
- `id => (...)` - [Стрелочная функция](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), почти аналог для `function(id){return {id: id};}`
- `{id}` - [Синтаксический сахар](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) для `{id: id}`

```js
var list = ["12", "31", "3", "12"].map(function(id) {
  return {id: id};
});

var dest = {title: "Список пользователей"};
dest.users = list;
console.log(JSON.stringify(dest));
console.log(dest);
```

Comment: а как работает id в фигурных скобочках, это литерал объекта?

Comment: @mymedia, это синтаксический сахар для `{id: id}`

Comment: И поддержка браузерами никакая, ага :)

Comment: @andreymal, кого это волнует, если есть babel?

Comment: @vp_arth всех тех, кто не юзает babel (:

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, не знал насчёт map, что так можно сделать.